# Convergence of this sum $\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{1}{n^aln^b(n)}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I need to find out for what parameters a,b converge/diverge this sum.I tried integral test and i know that it converge for a>1 but i do not know how to continue.Thanks in advance for advice.

> $$\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{1}{n^aln^b(n)}$$

Comment: Hint: $\ln n = o(n^\epsilon)$ for any $\epsilon > 0$ however small, which proves divergence if $a < 1$.

Comment: Are you sure the sum starts at $1$? The reason I ask is because if we have a $\ln(1)$ in the denominator, then the first term is undefined.

Comment: @ConnorHarris That is not true for all values of b(Take for example b=0)

Comment: @miraunpajaro Huh? If $b = 0$, then the sum is just $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^a}$, which also diverges if $a < 1$.

Comment: @Connor Harris My bad. I thought your comment said convergence. I somehow managed to misread it

Comment: It would probably be a good idea to start the sum at $n=2$ instead of $n=1$, since otherwise you have a power of $\ln(1)=0$ in the denominator.

Answer (score 0):

This is a special case of the [Generalized harmonic series of type 2](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serie_armonica) (found only italian link)

Which is :

$$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{n^{\alpha}\log^{\beta}(n)} \begin{cases} \text{converges }\hspace{0.2cm} \alpha > 1 \vee \alpha = 1 \wedge \beta > 1 \\ +\infty  \hspace{0.2cm} \alpha < 1 \vee \alpha = 1 \wedge \beta \leq 1  \end{cases}$$

Typically you reach this conclusion using [Cauhcy condensation test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_condensation_test) and asymptotic comparison with the generalized harmonic series $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{n^{\alpha}}$

Comment: If you read French, they're known in France as [Bertrand's series](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Série_de_Bertrand). There are also Spanish an Romanian versions.

Comment: Thanks! I really didn't know that, should i re-edit it ? @Bernard